# Ember.js update model after save

Tags: authentication, ember.js

I have a small Ember app and adding in authentication at the moment with a simple API in the background:

```
POST /login
//returns
{
  "token": "Much53cr4t"
}
```

Ember model for login (route setup correctly and calls the endpoint as expected)

```
App.Login = DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr(),
  password: DS.attr(),
  token: DS.attr()
});
```

Controller

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  // Implement your controller here.
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      var self = this;
      var login = self.get('model');
      login.set('username', self.get('username'));
      login.set('password', self.get('password'));
      login.save().then(function (result) {
        //do something here?
      });
   }
 }
```

});

I would like to get the returned `token` value to be added either to the created model before save, or new one. Whichever is easier. Can't seem to find any other advice other than 'return an id' but that I would consider not the best when it comes to an AUTH API endpoint like this.

Comment: Why do you have a model declared for a login object? You only have to log in once, so you're only ever going to send one object to the server once. It's overkill. Why not just use a plain AJAX call?

Comment: I wanted to use a model to handle the session, and do the login as well... you're right should have done it easier.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up adding a custom REST adapter for this:

```
App.LoginAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1',
  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var p = this._super(store, type, record);

    return p.then(function(data){
      record.set('token', data['token']);
    });
  },
});
```

Still wonder is there an easier, or more 'Ember-way' for doing this?